# How to add type of argument without breaking the return type from callback in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have `create` function that take a function and returns the type of the inner function.

```
function create<T>(callback: () => T): T {
  return callback();
}
const numberType: number = create(() => 1); // type is number

const stringType: string = create(() => 'foo'); // type is string
```

As you can see typescript is calculate the type that returns from the inner function.
`numberType` is `number` type and `stringType` is `string` type.
Base on what returning from the inner function.

**So typescript can detect what is the type by itself.**

I made a copy of `create` to `create2`. in `create2` I want to add argument to the inner function and provide the type for this argument from `create2` function.

By doing so the `create2` breaks because now it returns the type I provide to the `create2`:

```
 function create<T>(callback: () => T): T {
  return callback();
}

const numberType = create(() => 1); // type is number

const stringType = create(() => 'foo'); // type is string

// //////////////
function create2<T>(callback: (arg: T) => T): T {
  return callback(null);
}

const numberType2 = create2<{ data: string }>(({ data }) => 1); // type is number

const stringType2 = create2<{ is: boolean }>(({ is }) => 'foo'); // type is string
```

Any idea how to make `create2` to return the inner function type as `create` does? and to get type for argument in the inner function?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ls7wgn?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

This problem essentially boils down to the issue that TypeScript does not have [partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).

In your `create2` function you would need two generic types. The type `T` to represent the shape of the `arg` and another type `S` to infer the return type of the function.

```
function create2<T, S>(callback: (arg: T) => S): S {
  return callback(null);
}
```

But this does not really work because you can't explicitly give a type for `T` and let TypeScript automatically infer the generic type `S` (that feature simply does not exist yet).

So specifying both types would work here.

```
const numberType2 = create2<{ data: string }, number>(({ data }) => 1); // type is number
```

But I guess this is not really what you want to happen.

A way to solve this could be [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

```
function create3<T>() {
  return <S,>(callback: (arg: T) => S): S => callback(null as unknown as T)
}
```

By returning a second generic function inside `create3` we can have one function where an explicit generic type can be given and  one function where the generic type is inferred.

```
const numberType2 = create3<{ data: string }>()(({ data }) => 1); // type is number

const stringType2 = create3<{ is: boolean }>()(({ is }) => 'foo'); // type is string
```

---

Also there is a second major problem with the `create` function. As it is currently written, you only supply the shape of `T` with the generic type. That makes it impossible for the `create` function to supply an object of the correct type to the callback. There is simply no runtime information available.

Since `T` is unconstrained, you could supply any type here. Let's say `{ a: string }`. How should `create` know now to instaniate an object of this type? It's impossible.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=85&pln=6&pc=1#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigJwKYEMYYMwA8AKgHwAUAlMgN7DLKYxhooEDKANOVFgDa8AjLFADWALmRksaAOYSiVALwlkbChLbJlqPoOEiyEMP2RYAzskgiICAO4pzyBcAC%20wYFCRmYyIwFsBDDQiAE8ABwwAJi1UTBx8AmpkABMcLAlvNDgIGWQXcgoyMiTUmCw8pRUARgoAbmQAegbkGHCMZDgLf0C0d08Ib2RM7JlQiOjFWOxcQiTOiQEEBF5sFHzKIrmLF0rkAHIQJb26xubWiI6LYZygA)